# 2D linear interpolation in R with non-equally spaced values

Tags: r, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a question concerning 2D interpolation of non-equally spaced values in R. I was able to do a 2D linear interpolation with equally-spaced values using the `interp2()` from the `pracma` package (see example below).

**Equally-spaced 2D linear interpolation**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

### 2D interpolation with equally-spaced values ###

# Create sample data
data <- expand_grid(val1 = c(seq(1, 5, 1)), val2 = seq(1, 5, 1))
df <- data %>% mutate(z = val1 *val2)

# Transform into matrix
mat <- reshape2::acast(df, val1~val2, value.var="z" )
mat
#>   1  2  3  4  5
#> 1 1  2  3  4  5
#> 2 2  4  6  8 10
#> 3 3  6  9 12 15
#> 4 4  8 12 16 20
#> 5 5 10 15 20 25

# Show plot
lattice::levelplot(mat)
```

[image]

```r
# Create vectors containing coordinates for interpolation
interp_coords <- expand_grid(val1 = seq(1, 5, 0.1), val2 = seq(1, 5, 0.1))

# Interpolate using the interp() from the pracma library
interp_vals <- pracma::interp2(y = c(seq(1, 5, 1)), x = seq(1, 5, 1), Z = mat, xp = interp_coords$val1, yp = interp_coords$val2)

# Bind in new df, convert to matrix and plot
df_2 <- cbind(interp_coords, interp_vals)
mat2 <- reshape2::acast(df_2, val1~val2, value.var="interp_vals" )
lattice::levelplot(mat2)
```

[image]

**Non-equally spaced 2D linear interpolation**

Next, I tried to accomplish the same with a non-equally-spaced dataset (see image below; `c(seq(1, 5, 1), seq(6, 10, 2)`).

```r
### 2D interpolation with NON-equally spaced values ###
# Create sample data
df <- expand_grid(val1 = c(seq(1, 5, 1), seq(6, 10, 2)), val2 = seq(1, 5, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(z = val1 *val2)

# Transform into matrix
mat <- reshape2::acast(df, val1~val2, value.var="z" )
mat
#>     1  2  3  4  5
#> 1   1  2  3  4  5
#> 2   2  4  6  8 10
#> 3   3  6  9 12 15
#> 4   4  8 12 16 20
#> 5   5 10 15 20 25
#> 6   6 12 18 24 30
#> 8   8 16 24 32 40
#> 10 10 20 30 40 50
# Show plot
lattice::levelplot(mat)
```

[image]

Apparently, something goes wrong with the interpolation, and I do not understand what it is.

```r
# Create vectors containing coordinates for interpolation
interp_coords <- expand_grid(val1 = seq(1, 10, 0.1), val2 = seq(1, 5, 0.1))

# Interpolate using the interp() from the pracma library
interp_vals <- pracma::interp2(y = c(seq(1, 5, 1), seq(6, 10, 2)), x = seq(1, 5, 1), Z = mat, xp = interp_coords$val1, yp = interp_coords$val2)

# Bind in new df, convert to matrix and plot
df_2 <- cbind(interp_coords, interp_vals)
mat2 <- reshape2::acast(df_2, val1~val2, value.var="interp_vals" )
lattice::levelplot(mat2)
```

[image]

**Question**

How can I perform a non-equally spaced 2D linear interpolation in R?

<sup>Created on 2020-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have simply mixed up the `xp` and `yp` arguments of `interp2`:

```r
# Create vectors containing coordinates for interpolation
interp_coords <- expand_grid(val1 = seq(1, 10, 0.1), val2 = seq(1, 5, 0.1))

# Interpolate using the interp() from the pracma library
interp_vals <- pracma::interp2(y  = c(seq(1, 5, 1), seq(6, 10, 2)), 
                               x  = seq(1, 5, 1), Z = mat, 
                               xp = interp_coords$val2, 
                               yp = interp_coords$val1)

# Bind in new df, convert to matrix and plot
df_2 <- cbind(interp_coords, interp_vals)
mat2 <- reshape2::acast(df_2, val1~val2, value.var="interp_vals" )
lattice::levelplot(mat2)
```

[image]

Comment: @user213544 Ah! I see what you've done - see my update.

Comment: Very long question for a simple mixup indeed :p, thanks for the solution! Hopefully, someone else will benefit also from the examples:)

Comment: @user213544 it's a well written and reproducible question. Definitely worth leaving up, since the question itself makes a good tutorial on 2D interpolation.